# Implicit function theorem for conservation law

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

Can someone explain me how using the implicit function theorem get the following result

Given $u_0(x) = u(x,0)$, $f'(u)$ and the implicit function
$$F = u(x,t) - u_0(x-f'(u)t) = 0$$

compute the derivative of $u$ w.r.t. $x$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{-u'_0}{1+u'_0f''(u)t}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u(x,t)-u_0(x-f'(u)t)=0\Rightarrow u=u_0(x-f'(u)t)\Rightarrow\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u_0(x-f'(u)t)$$
The right side is equal to (using chain rule):
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u_0(x-f'(u)t)=u'_0\cdot(1-f''(u)t\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})$$
So we have 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=u'_0\cdot(1-f''(u)t\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})$$
Rearranging it yields
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{u'_0}{1+u'_0f''(u)t}$$